# Remove Dots from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have urls like this https://example.com/ECS-.327-12.5-12-C-TR which i want to redirect to https://example.com/ecs-327-125-12-c-tr removing dots form url i already have code that converts uppercase to lowercase so thats not a problem but dots in url are creating issue

i tried with following rule but no luck

RewriteRule ^([^/]*).([^/]*)\$ /$1$2.html [L,R=301]

Comment: Try using `\G[^./]+\K\.` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/R4lTt7/1

Answer (score 0):

the dot stands for any character except newline.
i think you have to escape it

```
RewriteRule ^([^/])\.([^/])\$ /$1$2.html [L,R=301]
```

i dont really understand what it should do but now it finds the character before a point, the point, and the character after the point

Comment: Let me try although i solved it by php using strtolower and explode methods and changing url to what i needed but will give htaccess solution try now